# MySQL - problemas de instalação com linux

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, linux

Problemas com instalação de MySQL em um linux.
 Toda vez que coloco no terminal o comando:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Me retorna esta mensagem:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 atom : Depends: git
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Já não sei o que pode estar ocorrendo, é a primeira instalação do MySQL dentro do SO.

Comment: Tenta rodar o comando `apt-get -f install` ele deve instalar as dependências necessárias

Comment: @LeoBufalo: Qual é a distribuição e versão GNU/Linux que utiliza?

Comment: Neste exemplo estava utilizando o Deepin, porém apenas fiz o que o @Wilker disse e resolveu!!

Comment: @Wilker cria uma resposta para o autor marcar como solução!

Comment: @JuniorNunes o rapaz abaixo já transformou o meu comentário em resposta explicando os comandos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que não há problema na instalação do MySQL mas sim alguma instalação anterior incompleta (*broken*). Pela mensagem de erro consta que houve tentativa de instalação do pacote `atom`, mas faltou a instalação da dependência `git`.

Na mensagem de erro encontra-se uma das possíveis soluções, que é rodar

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get -f install
```

onde a opção -f significa *fix broken*.

Outra solução é remover o pacote que está com dependências pendentes de instalação:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove atom
```

Após ação de correção do erro, repita os passos de instalação do MySQL.

---

Para reduzir possibilidades de erro, e caso seja novato na utilização de GNU/Linux & MySQL, sugiro que instale os pacotes do MySQL que façam parte dos repositórios da distribuição e não os pacotes dos repositórios do MySQL.

As instruções de instalação do MySQL 5.7 em distribuição GNU/Linux (derivada do) Debian encontram-se em [A Quick Guide to Using the MySQL APT Repository](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/).

Comment: Excelente resposta, realmente era isso mesmo, agradeço o apoio.